# Win8: The program can't start because MSVCR71.dll is missing from your system

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-office

I am trying to install Office 2007 Standard on Windows 8.  When I attempt installation, I get an error saying `"The program can't start because MSVCR71.dll is missing from your system."`  I've looked and the DLL is not in either the System32 or the SysWOW64 folder.

I've tried downloading the DLL and rebooting, but I got the same error.  I've tried running `regsrv32 msvcr71.dll` in a command prompt, but I get an error saying `"The module msvcr71.dll failed to load.  Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with binary or dependent .DLL files."`

Google told me that the DLL is part of Visual C Runtime.  I've tried reinstalling that, but the DLL did not appear.  I do have DLLs called `msvcr100.dll` and `msvcr110.dll`, so it is probably an old version.

I'm not sure what else to try, and Google hasn't been much help.  Office 2007 is listed as [compatible](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Type=Software&Name=Microsoft+Office+2007+Standard&ModelOrVersion=12&Vendor=Microsoft&Locale=&LastSearchTerm=&BreadcrumbPath=&TempOsid=Windows+8) with Windows 8.

Comment: That file is part of .NET 1.1, which isn't really support in 8+. Are you running Windows 8.0, or 8.1? Strangely though, I installed Office 2007 (Ultimate) on my Windows 8 and 8.1 computers in the past (a couple times) and never needed to install .Net 1.1, nor did it complain about that file. How are you installing it exactly, and at which point during the install does the error pop up?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'm running Windows 8.  The install is coming through a corporate download.  The installation complains immediately after clicking install.

Comment: "The install is coming through a corporate download" can you expand on that? Like what exactly do you mean by that (it could mean a few things)?  Have you discussed this with your corporate IT staff?  They may be using some weird wrapper to do the install that needs that file when Office itself doesn't...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 My company has a web application that it uses to distribute software to its employees.  The error is unlikely to be in the application itself, as I've been able to install several other pieces of software through it and the error pops up after the Microsoft Office splash screen.  It is possible, I suppose, that the company created a custom installer and that's what's causing the problem.  I've submitted a ticket but I figured I'd try to find an answer while I wait.

Comment: Your installing the wrong version of the VC++ runtime as other pointed out your likely want at least the 2005 package if not earlier.  You can't solve this without Afministrator access

Comment: @Ramhound I have administrator access.  I've attempted installing 2003, but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you installed the version that installs that version of the dll?  The next version it could be could be VC++ 2001 but I don't that even exists since and even if it did that's nearly decade and half old time to update your software links if that's the acse.